Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 youtube video lagging
Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 youtube video lagging
It happened some time first time i download blix(email client software) and after installed it i notice that make my youtube videoo lagging either chrome and firefox after i deleted blix it fix but time pass it happened agian. so what's the real cause of this problem and how to fix it.
I noticed another cause of this when i mute the video the lagging is disappear maybe it's because my sound problem ?
but when i using my earphone jack everything is fine...
enter image description here
========== Huawei matebook d15 ==========

Theses comments are more info for the question and need to be added to the question with the edit function. Comments are for someone trying to help you asking for more info.

IF you use an addblocker: this is done by google and intentional.
